# Share Array Reference between JavaScript and ActionScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, flash, pass-by-reference

I have been working with the WebcamJS library to stream video from the camera in the browser, but I have run into a major performance bottleneck. Since I am using Internet Explorer 11 (and **cannot** switch to a different browser), this library reverts to a Flash fallback for accessing the camera.

The ActionScript callback that returns the image is prohibitively slow, due to its many steps. When it returns the image, it first encodes its byte array as a PNG or JPG, and then to a base 64 string. This string is then passed using ExternalInterface to JavaScript, which decodes the image through a data URI. Given that all I need is the byte array in JavaScript, these extra steps seem wasteful.

I have had to tackle a similar problem before, in C++/Python. Rather than repeatedly pass the array data back and forth between the two languages, I used Python to pass a NumPy array reference at the start of the program. Then, they could both access the same data from then on without any extra communication.

Now that you understand my situation, here is the question: is it possible to pass a JavaScript Array or ArrayBuffer by reference to ActionScript? In that case, I could have ActionScript modify the JavaScript array directly, rather than waste time converting, encoding, and decoding the image for each  frame.

(WebcamJS: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs)

Comment: I might have actually just found the answer to my own problem, through SharedObjects:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860839/passing-an-actionscript-jpg-byte-array-to-javascript-and-eventually-to-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010707/as3-store-array-in-shared-object

Comment: For anyone else with the same problem who comes here in the future, SharedObjects actually _don't_ seem to be the answer. It looks as though the feature I want is absent from JavaScript/ActionScript.

I was able to get better performance, however, by using this camera library instead:
https://github.com/macobo/meemoo-camcanvas

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, SharedObjects in flash store data, serialised with the AMF protocol, on the file system (in a very specific, sandboxed and locked place) where Javascript has no way to access to read the data.

Have you tried to simply call the ExternalInterface method and pass an array of bytes as an argument? it would be passed by value, automatically converted from the Actionscript data structure to the Javascript one, but you'd skip all the encoding steps and it should be fast enough ...